# What new types of environments are possible on an intelligently designed habitat?

Tags: biology, environment, space-constructs, habitability

Humans have taken the stars and are capable of building pretty much anything they want(but the laws of physics are still the same), and a group of them decide they want to make a habitat with a completely new set of biomes, just for fun and because everyone's tired of the earth ones. They can genetically modify organisms to fit any niches they make and they can use technological "hacks" to create biomes otherwise impossible or unlikely. For example, they could use domes to make the atmosphere stretch thousands of miles up, or they could use heating coils hidden in the earth to create heat without geothermic activity. They could completely shift the balance of elements; maybe a biome has mercury lakes and oceans...etc.

The rules are as follows: 
1) If uneducated humans set foot on the world or space habitat, they wouldn't notice any of the technology being used.

2) A human in a modern space-suit would have to be able to survive for at least 5 minutes in this climate.

3) Organisms can only get energy from the sun or from heat(they can also eat each other).

4) The biology is limited to anything that can be achieved with earth DNA, and the biomes must be inhabited.

**Essentially**: What environments can you think of that could exist if there was an intelligent design? Why types of organisms might be designed to fill those biomes?

Comment: without some more constraints the list is literally endless. this questions is very open ended.

Comment: @John It was supposed to be pretty open-ended, but I'll bring in some more constraints.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a biome. You could have a high-ish pressure atmosphere with a low gravity using a dome. The environment would probably have a lot of large flying animals, but because the pressure was high, maybe around 4 atmospheres, it would be a mix of swimming and flying. Animals with hydrogen sacks would float like blimps and maneuver with cilia, while smaller animals would have dolphin-like tails and wings.

Answer (score 0):

**Same as the previous ones**

If you ask a programmer what the first rule of programming is, you will get a wide variety of responses - one of them being 'Don't reinvent the wheel'. In other words, if you know a program works and it works really well, then there's no point in wasting time and effort into trying to make something different. More specialized, yes. A wholly new designed, no.

It's kind of hard to compare programming to designing creatures, but I'll give it a shot. Programming is very simple executable code that runs on a computer designed to execute that code, it follows very clear logic trails, and at any point you can test individual components to tell what's wrong. DNA altering, by contrast, is trying to run the entire thing on a universe which tends towards entropy, that is, screwing you over and is more complex than 99% of all modern programs by the order of *probably* a few hundred magnitudes. In other words, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel by programming, you *absolutely* don't want to reinvent the mouse when it comes to biomes. Biomes are insanely complex systems that are always on a knife edge when it comes to failing miserably and only doesn't because if the literal hundreds of built-in adjustments measures it's eventually managed to scrape through evolution.

Given that, you're not better off inventing a new biome on a ship, you are best off adapting a current one.